# VB.Net NullReferenceException

Tags: vb.net

At the line `If aryTemp(1) < aryTemp2(1) Then the

> Index was outside the bounds of the
>   array.

error appears. Can't figure it out why would it be outside array's bounds.
Basically trying to compare Last Names to sort the records and place em back into list box.

```
 Private Sub btnAscending_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAscending.Click
        'load all students into array
        Dim arySort(numberOfRecords) As String
        Dim aryTemp(6) As String
        Dim aryTemp2(6) As String
        For i = 0 To numberOfRecords - 1
            arySort(i) = lstListBox.Items(i)
        Next
        Dim temp As String 'holds temporary record
        Dim k As Integer
        For i = 0 To arySort.Length - 2
            aryTemp = Split(arySort(i), " ")
            For k = i + 1 To arySort.Length - 1
                aryTemp2 = Split(arySort(k), " ")
                If aryTemp(1) < aryTemp2(1) Then
                    temp = arySort(k)
                    arySort(k) = arySort(i)
                    arySort(i) = temp
                End If
            Next
        Next
        lstListBox.Items.Clear()
        numberOfRecords = 0
        isLoaded = False
        For i = 0 To arySort.Length - 1
            lstListBox.Items.Add(arySort(i))
            numberOfRecords += 1
        Next
        currentRecord = 0
        isLoaded = True
    End Sub
```

Comment: Where does your code throw more precisely?

Comment: Since when can you allocate an array in VB.NET without the `New` keyword? Isn't the proper syntax `Dim aryTemp as New String(6)`, or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

Well, either `arySort` or `lstListBox` is `Nothing` but without some more code I can't tell. A debugger might help.

Comment: Got it. The new problem is posted instead of original question.

Comment: Please don't do that. Post a new Question for a new question.

Answer (score 0):

A [`NullReferenceException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullreferenceexception.aspx) says it all.

> The exception that is thrown when there is an attempt to dereference a null object reference.

This means that you're trying to access a variable which actually isn't yet assigned a value, or the `Nothing` value is assigned. In the case of a class object, this would mean that your object is not instantiated.

In the case of your `ListBox`, it needs to be instantiated, if it is `Nothing`;

In the case of your array `arySort`, have you initialized it, or is it still `Nothing`?

When you're facing such a **NullReferenceException**, ask yourself whether you have all the  expected initializations and instantiations. When a variable is `Nothing` when it shouldn't be, ask yourself why is it so. This questionning of yourself will most likely guide you to the correct problem solving.

Another good practice is verifying whether a variable is `Nothing` before attempting to access it.

**EDIT #1**

> Index was outside the bounds of the array.

This is an **[`IndexOutOfRangeException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.indexoutofrangeexception.aspx)**.

> The exception that is thrown when an attempt is made to access an element of an array with an index that is outside the bounds of the array. This class cannot be inherited.

This exception is thrown whenever the attempt to access an array index which is actually outside its length.

```
object[] objects = new object() { 1, 2, 3 };

for (int index = 0; index <= objects.Length; index++) {
    // The following line will throw an `IndexOutOfRangeException` when index = objects.Length
    Console.WriteLine(objects[index].ToString());     
}
```

Because .NET arrays and collections are zero-based, that is, the first index of an array or a collection is 0, trying to access an index worth the length of an array might bring it out of bound. Actually, the length of object array is 3. Aside, accessing `objects[3]` will throw, since 3 is its length, and not its upper bound.

That said:

```
objects[0]; // This will return the object value of 1, the first value placed in the array.
objects[1]; // This will return the object value of 2, the second value placed in the array.
objects[2]; // This will return the object value of 3, the thrid value placed in the array.
objects[3]; // Throws the `IndexOutOfRangeException` here, 
            // as there is no value stored at this index, hance this index doesn't even exist
            // in the array!
```

To sum it up, you always have to consider a zero-based index, that is, the array length - 1.

```
for (int index = 0; index < objects.Length; i++)
    Console.WrilteLine(object[index]);
```

Which output will be:

```
1
2
3
```

Comment: Thanks for info('ll remember that) and I already found the solution. The new problem is still a problem.